# Search a MySQL database for similar characters

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to create a search of the database (MySQL) using PHP that would lookup part numbers for electrical components but want the search to also pick up on similar characters

Eg a search for 6se7o90 should also pick up 6se7090 and a search for 4i737a should also pick up 4l737a as the 0/o and i/l can look similar when printed on some part labels.

What is the best way of doing this in PHP / MySQL?

Comment: This is too broad for the scope of the site. Have you researched anything about the topic? Tried to write some code?

Comment: I have extensively Googled for this and can't find any answers. I have also started writing some code that does str_replace in a loop to run multiple queries but I can see this hammering the database in production

Comment: @MatthewTemple then you should share your attempt in the question, otherwise we do not know what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define a [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)-like function that simplifies the values to a "normal form". Then, searching will be easy.

For example, if you consider `o` and `0` identical and `|` and `1` as well, you can normalize them all to digits, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select
    *,
    replace(replace(value, 'o', '0'), '|', '1') as normal_form
  from t
) x
where normal_form = replace(replace('6se7o90', 'o', '0'), '|', '1')
```

**Note #1:** For simplicity and clarity, the normalization rules for the values can be externalized into a function.

**Note #2:** For high performance searches you can create an indexed virtual column with the normalized value.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just 1/l/I and 0/O and 2/Z and 5/S, do 2 things:

- Use a case-folding collation for the column, and
- Modify *both* the data in the table and the search criteria.  That is, *always* change l and I to 1, etc.

The first takes care of upper/lower case; the second takes care of confusables.

Also consider O/D, B/8, and who knows what else.

And trim spaces off the front and back end of the strings in the table and the search.